# Reactjs render component before other components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I specify that a component should be rendered absolutely before any other component?

I want to specify that `<Footer />` and all the child components of footer should be rendered before any other components.
The reason I want this is because I have code that depends on the html that footer is rendering which means that the reference to `<Footer />` is `undefined` in the other components if `<Footer />` doesn't render first.

Here's an example:

```
export default class Layout extends React.Component {
    ...
    render(){
        return (
            <Body />
            <Footer /> //Render first
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a little more details? Like a minimum code sample to see which kind of references you're talking about.

Comment: I figured that the best way to do it was to use another RenderDOM and render the footer separately first.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I see for you do do that is:

- Have the information about the **render status for the footer in a state**. (Let's assume your name it `isFooterRendered` and it is a boolean)
- You set `isFooterRendered` to be `false` in the initial state.
- You only render the children components when `isFooterRendered` is `true`
- In `componentDidMount` **you will have a reference to Footer**, set `isFooterRendered` to be true.

(Some people claim that it's bad to `setState` on `componentDidMount` but in your case looks like a legit use case, aside from that React Docs expose a [similar example](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html))